# Google Maps não carrega no dispositivo fisico

Tags: android, google-maps

Criei uma aplicação de estudos do Google Maps e no emulador Genymotion ele carrega normalmente mas num dispositivo físico ele não carrega completamente (estou a usar o Android Studio). Segue um print screen de como ele fica num dispositivo fisico:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para gerar a AI-Key, eu extrai o SHA-1 fingerprint através do seguinte comando:
`keytool -list -v -keystore "C:\Users\menda\Desktop\Meus APKs\Chaves\googlemaps2.jks" -alias googlemaps -storepass 123456 -keypass 123456`

Exportei o projecto assinado com a "debug.keystore" e mesmo assim não estou a conseguir carregar o Google Maps num dispositivo fisico (no emulador funciona perfeitamente). Seguem os prints dos passos que fiz:[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: É complicado opinar neste tipo de situação! Pela imagem parece me que não possui uma chave válida. Pois quando não há conexão ainda são exibidos os quadrantes. Crie a chave e deixe em branco os valores de SHA-1 e o pacote do app, para ver se funciona! Abraços

Comment: Thiago, em https://console.developers.google.com criei uma nova API-Key com os valores nome do pacote e SHA-1 em branco. O mapa desta forma também é mostrado como na imagem em cima. Sabe onde eu estou a falhar?

Comment: Se instalar o apk que você exportou no genymotion funciona? Ou só executando direto?

Comment: Emerson, no Android Studio se eu executar o projeto através do Genymotion, o mapa é carregado. Se no Android Studio no menu Build>Generate Signed APK criar um arquivo apk para instalar num dispositivo físico, o mapa no dispositivo físico não é carregado...

Comment: Eu devo estar a cometer algum tipo de erro em relação às chaves! Qual é a diferença entre a Keystore e a Key password?

Comment: Se eu através do Android Device Monitor enviar o arquivo APK para o emulador Genymotion e depois neste proceder à sua instalação, acontece o mesmo problema que no dispositivo físico, ou seja, desta forma o mapa também não é carregado!!!

Comment: Não sei o que pode ser, pelos prints parece que está certo. Recomendo criar uma keystore e usá-la tanto para debug como pra exportar o apk.

Comment: Emerson, fiz o que você me recomendou mas não funcionou, ou seja, no menu Build>Generate Signed APK, criei uma nova chave e capturei o seu valor SHA-1 com o seguinte comando "keytool -list -v -keystore "%USERPROFILE%\.android\chavetestes1.jks" -alias chavetestes1 -storepass 123456 -keypass 123456" e em  console.developers.google.com criei uma nova API-Key para aplicar no meu projeto. Instalei num dispositivo físico e continua a não funcionar!!?? Você podia-me enviar um apk de um projeto seu de testes para eu aqui confirmar se funciona? Obrigado.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui descobrir qual era o meu problema: Eu para exportar o arquivo APK para um dispositivo físico não podia inserir a API-Key no arquivo "google_maps_api.xml". Eu tinha antes de a inserir directamente no arquivo "AndroidManifest.xml", substituido a configuração:
`<meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/google_maps_key" />`
por

```
<meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.geo.API_KEY"
        android:value="xxx_minha_api_key_xxx" />
```

Obrigados a todos que me tentaram ajudar.

Answer (score -1):

Para o modo apk assinado no google play, você deve ir
Builds variantes (a esquerda da tela) e mudar do modo debug para release.